# How to save the output of picocom to a file

Tags: serial-port, logs

I'm using ( `sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0` ) to connect to a real-time embedded system based on ThreadX system.

Once I'm connected to this device, I use some ThreadX commands to display some logs.

Currently I'm using a manual copy past maneuver to save the logs.
Is there any other way to save all the output (logs) displayed on the terminal to a file on my computer?

Answer (score 8):

Using `tee`:

```
picocom /dev/ttyUSB1 -b 115200 -l | tee my.log
```

Answer (score 7):

picocom has a logging feature `-g`. You can use it like;

`picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0 -g my_picocom_logfile.txt`

from the manpage;

```
--logfile | -g
              Use specified file for logging (recording) serial input, and possibly serial output.  If the file exists, it is appended to.  Every
              character read from the serial port is written to the specified file (before input mapping is performed).  If local-echo mode is is enabled
              (see --echo option and C-c command), then every character written to the serial port (after output mapping is performed) is also logged to
              the same file.  (Default: no logging)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run it under `script` - see `man script` and do:

```
script my.log
sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
...
exit
```

And all the inputs and outpuits will be in `my.log`.

Comment: Great, that exactly what I need. Thank you very much !

Comment: @younlee Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if you found it useful.